# How to make TypeAliases Hashable

Tags: swift, types, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have the following definitions and a type alias:

```
`typealias Alien = AlienClass & AlienProtocol` 
`class AlienClass: SKSpriteNode {}`
`protocol AlienProtocol {}`
```

In order to store an object in a Set (or Map) it needs to be `Hashable`. `SKSpriteNode` is hashable, so I have no problem with `let s = Set<AlienClass>()`.

However, if I use `let s = Set<AlienClass>()` then I get the error `Protocol 'Alien' (aka 'AlienClass & AlienProtocol') as a type cannot conform to 'Hashable'`.

Is there any way to force the `typealias` to inherit the hash function from its underlying `AlienClass` (which itself inherits from `SKSpriteNode`)?

I ran into this same issue when trying to store protocols in Sets directly. I stumbled upon Type Erasure but this doesn’t seem to work for heterogenous objects in the set. My **hacky** workaround has been to store the objects implementing the interface in a map like so: `var AlienProtocols: [SKSpriteNode: AlienProtocol] = [:]`. This really isn't great though, so a better pattern would be helpful.

Comment: You have a type via your typealias that contains a protocol and a protocol can not conform to another protocol so no your type alias will not work.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson does this mean that there is no way to make a type alias or protocol “hashable”? Is my map solution the only way? That’s seem really limiting in the case where you have a bunch of heterogenous objects that all have a few of the same methods or properties.

Comment: Typealias is not a type

Comment: But what is the real purposes of your typealias, right now it defines custom types that are sub classes of AlienClass and implements the AlienProtocol? For your Set, wouldn't it be enough if they are subclasses for instance?